# Type is missing from type (TS2740) - cant override interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a library called "`@ww/react-ui-components`"
This library contains `Paper` component, which extends the functionality of `Paper` from material ui.

This is how the .d.ts file of my Paper looks like (generated in the build):

```
import React, { RefObject } from 'react';
import { PaperProps } from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { WWAttributesProps } from 'hoc/withWindwardAttributes';
export declare type Props = PaperProps & {
    rootElRef?: RefObject<any>;
    withHoverEffect?: boolean;
};
declare const _default: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<import("../hoc/withWindwardAttributes").Attributes & Pick<PaperProps & {
    rootElRef?: React.RefObject<any> | undefined;
    withHoverEffect?: boolean | undefined;
} & WWAttributesProps, "slot" | "style" | "title" | "ref" | "classes" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | "accessKey" | "className" | "contentEditable" | "contextMenu" | "dir" | "draggable" | "hidden" | "id" | "lang" | "placeholder" | "spellCheck" | "tabIndex" | "translate" | "radioGroup" | "role" | "about" | "datatype" | "inlist" | "prefix" | "property" | "resource" | "typeof" | "vocab" | "autoCapitalize" | "autoCorrect" | "autoSave" | "color" | "itemProp" | "itemScope" | "itemType" | "itemID" | "itemRef" | "results" | "security" | "unselectable" | "inputMode" | "is" | "css" | "aria-activedescendant" | "aria-atomic" | "aria-autocomplete" | "aria-busy" | "aria-checked" | "aria-colcount" | "aria-colindex" | "aria-colspan" | "aria-controls" | "aria-current" | "aria-describedby" | "aria-details" | "aria-disabled" | "aria-dropeffect" | "aria-errormessage" | "aria-expanded" | "aria-flowto" | "aria-grabbed" | "aria-haspopup" | "aria-hidden" | "aria-invalid" | "aria-keyshortcuts" | "aria-label" | "aria-labelledby" | "aria-level" | "aria-live" | "aria-modal" | "aria-multiline" | "aria-multiselectable" | "aria-orientation" | "aria-owns" | "aria-placeholder" | "aria-posinset" | "aria-pressed" | "aria-readonly" | "aria-relevant" | "aria-required" | "aria-roledescription" | "aria-rowcount" | "aria-rowindex" | "aria-rowspan" | "aria-selected" | "aria-setsize" | "aria-sort" | "aria-valuemax" | "aria-valuemin" | "aria-valuenow" | "aria-valuetext" | "children" | "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" | "onCopy" | "onCopyCapture" | "onCut" | "onCutCapture" | "onPaste" | "onPasteCapture" | "onCompositionEnd" | "onCompositionEndCapture" | "onCompositionStart" | "onCompositionStartCapture" | "onCompositionUpdate" | "onCompositionUpdateCapture" | "onFocus" | "onFocusCapture" | "onBlur" | "onBlurCapture" | "onChange" | "onChangeCapture" | "onBeforeInput" | "onBeforeInputCapture" | "onInput" | "onInputCapture" | "onReset" | "onResetCapture" | "onSubmit" | "onSubmitCapture" | "onInvalid" | "onInvalidCapture" | "onLoad" | "onLoadCapture" | "onError" | "onErrorCapture" | "onKeyDown" | "onKeyDownCapture" | "onKeyPress" | "onKeyPressCapture" | "onKeyUp" | "onKeyUpCapture" | "onAbort" | "onAbortCapture" | "onCanPlay" | "onCanPlayCapture" | "onCanPlayThrough" | "onCanPlayThroughCapture" | "onDurationChange" | "onDurationChangeCapture" | "onEmptied" | "onEmptiedCapture" | "onEncrypted" | "onEncryptedCapture" | "onEnded" | "onEndedCapture" | "onLoadedData" | "onLoadedDataCapture" | "onLoadedMetadata" | "onLoadedMetadataCapture" | "onLoadStart" | "onLoadStartCapture" | "onPause" | "onPauseCapture" | "onPlay" | "onPlayCapture" | "onPlaying" | "onPlayingCapture" | "onProgress" | "onProgressCapture" | "onRateChange" | "onRateChangeCapture" | "onSeeked" | "onSeekedCapture" | "onSeeking" | "onSeekingCapture" | "onStalled" | "onStalledCapture" | "onSuspend" | "onSuspendCapture" | "onTimeUpdate" | "onTimeUpdateCapture" | "onVolumeChange" | "onVolumeChangeCapture" | "onWaiting" | "onWaitingCapture" | "onAuxClick" | "onAuxClickCapture" | "onClick" | "onClickCapture" | "onContextMenu" | "onContextMenuCapture" | "onDoubleClick" | "onDoubleClickCapture" | "onDrag" | "onDragCapture" | "onDragEnd" | "onDragEndCapture" | "onDragEnter" | "onDragEnterCapture" | "onDragExit" | "onDragExitCapture" | "onDragLeave" | "onDragLeaveCapture" | "onDragOver" | "onDragOverCapture" | "onDragStart" | "onDragStartCapture" | "onDrop" | "onDropCapture" | "onMouseDown" | "onMouseDownCapture" | "onMouseEnter" | "onMouseLeave" | "onMouseMove" | "onMouseMoveCapture" | "onMouseOut" | "onMouseOutCapture" | "onMouseOver" | "onMouseOverCapture" | "onMouseUp" | "onMouseUpCapture" | "onSelect" | "onSelectCapture" | "onTouchCancel" | "onTouchCancelCapture" | "onTouchEnd" | "onTouchEndCapture" | "onTouchMove" | "onTouchMoveCapture" | "onTouchStart" | "onTouchStartCapture" | "onPointerDown" | "onPointerDownCapture" | "onPointerMove" | "onPointerMoveCapture" | "onPointerUp" | "onPointerUpCapture" | "onPointerCancel" | "onPointerCancelCapture" | "onPointerEnter" | "onPointerEnterCapture" | "onPointerLeave" | "onPointerLeaveCapture" | "onPointerOver" | "onPointerOverCapture" | "onPointerOut" | "onPointerOutCapture" | "onGotPointerCapture" | "onGotPointerCaptureCapture" | "onLostPointerCapture" | "onLostPointerCaptureCapture" | "onScroll" | "onScrollCapture" | "onWheel" | "onWheelCapture" | "onAnimationStart" | "onAnimationStartCapture" | "onAnimationEnd" | "onAnimationEndCapture" | "onAnimationIteration" | "onAnimationIterationCapture" | "onTransitionEnd" | "onTransitionEndCapture" | "component" | "elevation" | "square" | "variant" | "innerRef" | "rootElRef" | "withHoverEffect">, "slot" | "style" | "title" | "classes" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | "accessKey" | "className" | "contentEditable" | "contextMenu" | "dir" | "draggable" | "hidden" | "id" | "lang" | "placeholder" | "spellCheck" | "tabIndex" | "translate" | "radioGroup" | "role" | "about" | "datatype" | "inlist" | "prefix" | "property" | "resource" | "typeof" | "vocab" | "autoCapitalize" | "autoCorrect" | "autoSave" | "color" | "itemProp" | "itemScope" | "itemType" | "itemID" | "itemRef" | "results" | "security" | "unselectable" | "inputMode" | "is" | "css" | "aria-activedescendant" | "aria-atomic" | "aria-autocomplete" | "aria-busy" | "aria-checked" | "aria-colcount" | "aria-colindex" | "aria-colspan" | "aria-controls" | "aria-current" | "aria-describedby" | "aria-details" | "aria-disabled" | "aria-dropeffect" | "aria-errormessage" | "aria-expanded" | "aria-flowto" | "aria-grabbed" | "aria-haspopup" | "aria-hidden" | "aria-invalid" | "aria-keyshortcuts" | "aria-label" | "aria-labelledby" | "aria-level" | "aria-live" | "aria-modal" | "aria-multiline" | "aria-multiselectable" | "aria-orientation" | "aria-owns" | "aria-placeholder" | "aria-posinset" | "aria-pressed" | "aria-readonly" | "aria-relevant" | "aria-required" | "aria-roledescription" | "aria-rowcount" | "aria-rowindex" | "aria-rowspan" | "aria-selected" | "aria-setsize" | "aria-sort" | "aria-valuemax" | "aria-valuemin" | "aria-valuenow" | "aria-valuetext" | "children" | "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" | "onCopy" | "onCopyCapture" | "onCut" | "onCutCapture" | "onPaste" | "onPasteCapture" | "onCompositionEnd" | "onCompositionEndCapture" | "onCompositionStart" | "onCompositionStartCapture" | "onCompositionUpdate" | "onCompositionUpdateCapture" | "onFocus" | "onFocusCapture" | "onBlur" | "onBlurCapture" | "onChange" | "onChangeCapture" | "onBeforeInput" | "onBeforeInputCapture" | "onInput" | "onInputCapture" | "onReset" | "onResetCapture" | "onSubmit" | "onSubmitCapture" | "onInvalid" | "onInvalidCapture" | "onLoad" | "onLoadCapture" | "onError" | "onErrorCapture" | "onKeyDown" | "onKeyDownCapture" | "onKeyPress" | "onKeyPressCapture" | "onKeyUp" | "onKeyUpCapture" | "onAbort" | "onAbortCapture" | "onCanPlay" | "onCanPlayCapture" | "onCanPlayThrough" | "onCanPlayThroughCapture" | "onDurationChange" | "onDurationChangeCapture" | "onEmptied" | "onEmptiedCapture" | "onEncrypted" | "onEncryptedCapture" | "onEnded" | "onEndedCapture" | "onLoadedData" | "onLoadedDataCapture" | "onLoadedMetadata" | "onLoadedMetadataCapture" | "onLoadStart" | "onLoadStartCapture" | "onPause" | "onPauseCapture" | "onPlay" | "onPlayCapture" | "onPlaying" | "onPlayingCapture" | "onProgress" | "onProgressCapture" | "onRateChange" | "onRateChangeCapture" | "onSeeked" | "onSeekedCapture" | "onSeeking" | "onSeekingCapture" | "onStalled" | "onStalledCapture" | "onSuspend" | "onSuspendCapture" | "onTimeUpdate" | "onTimeUpdateCapture" | "onVolumeChange" | "onVolumeChangeCapture" | "onWaiting" | "onWaitingCapture" | "onAuxClick" | "onAuxClickCapture" | "onClick" | "onClickCapture" | "onContextMenu" | "onContextMenuCapture" | "onDoubleClick" | "onDoubleClickCapture" | "onDrag" | "onDragCapture" | "onDragEnd" | "onDragEndCapture" | "onDragEnter" | "onDragEnterCapture" | "onDragExit" | "onDragExitCapture" | "onDragLeave" | "onDragLeaveCapture" | "onDragOver" | "onDragOverCapture" | "onDragStart" | "onDragStartCapture" | "onDrop" | "onDropCapture" | "onMouseDown" | "onMouseDownCapture" | "onMouseEnter" | "onMouseLeave" | "onMouseMove" | "onMouseMoveCapture" | "onMouseOut" | "onMouseOutCapture" | "onMouseOver" | "onMouseOverCapture" | "onMouseUp" | "onMouseUpCapture" | "onSelect" | "onSelectCapture" | "onTouchCancel" | "onTouchCancelCapture" | "onTouchEnd" | "onTouchEndCapture" | "onTouchMove" | "onTouchMoveCapture" | "onTouchStart" | "onTouchStartCapture" | "onPointerDown" | "onPointerDownCapture" | "onPointerMove" | "onPointerMoveCapture" | "onPointerUp" | "onPointerUpCapture" | "onPointerCancel" | "onPointerCancelCapture" | "onPointerEnter" | "onPointerEnterCapture" | "onPointerLeave" | "onPointerLeaveCapture" | "onPointerOver" | "onPointerOverCapture" | "onPointerOut" | "onPointerOutCapture" | "onGotPointerCapture" | "onGotPointerCaptureCapture" | "onLostPointerCapture" | "onLostPointerCaptureCapture" | "onScroll" | "onScrollCapture" | "onWheel" | "onWheelCapture" | "onAnimationStart" | "onAnimationStartCapture" | "onAnimationEnd" | "onAnimationEndCapture" | "onAnimationIteration" | "onAnimationIterationCapture" | "onTransitionEnd" | "onTransitionEndCapture" | "component" | "elevation" | "square" | "variant" | "innerRef" | "rootElRef" | "withHoverEffect" | "wwComponentName"> & React.RefAttributes<unknown>>;
export default _default;
```

I have another library called "`@ww/ofv-ui-components`" which imports `Paper` from '`@ww/react-ui-components`"
When I use it, I get the following error:

```
Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Attributes & Pick<any, "placeholder" | "onChange" | "children" | "classes" | "defaultValue" | "defaultChecked" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | ... 255 more ... | "withHoverEffect">, "placeholder" | ... 262 more ... | "withHoverEffect">': placeholder, onChange, classes, defaultValue, and 258 more.ts
```

I tried to override the `Paper` interface by creating `modules.d.ts` file in "`@ww/ofv-ui-components`" and used `any` just to see if it works - which it didnt.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to override it somehow? I dont want to suppress the error or ignore it..
I want to fix it properly

Comment: Can you reproduce it in https://codesandbox.io/ or https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @caTS sine I am using private libraries I cant really reproduce it elsewhere :/

Comment: Sorry then, it's very hard and unlikely for someone to be able to answer with certainty.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to use `Partial` in the default export? `Partial<Pick< ... >>`...

Comment: @caTS I was thinking about the Partial, but it's not me adding the Pick, it's automatically in the build process of the types that creates this type with Pick and the rest so I dont know where it's coming from

Comment: Well, I'm just saying that if you somehow add in the Partial, it'll fix the problem. Good luck!